# JavaScript Object Contains inherit Property

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that when I try to create a JavaScript object in it using:

var myVar = {};

The resulting object always contains an inherit property, this interferes with my code and doesn't happen except on this page only, anyone knows why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somebody done gone and put somethin on `Object.prototype`. Check it yourself:

```
for(var k in {}) alert(k); // should get NO alerts
```

As for tracking it down, use the output of above to search your codebase. First places to check are any external libraries you are including in `<script src="..."></script>` tags. For example really old versions of the Prototype library augmented `Object.prototype`.

*Update re comment from @Ahmad*:

You have two choices:

1. Move the implementation *off* the prototype to instead take the thing to extend as the first parameter, eg:

   ```
   Object.inherit = function(obj, superClass, superClassName) {
     /* change "this" to "obj" all throughout the code here */
   }
   ```

   And refactor *all* places that do:

   ```
   foo.inherit(a, b)
   ```

   to instead do:

   ```
   Object.inherit(foo, a, b)
   ```

   This approach may require a large re-factoring effort obviously. The benefit is you leave `Object.prototype` alone.
2. The 2nd approach is to leave the code that does `Object.prototype.inherit = ...` alone, and instead refactor the code you are trying to write right now to use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:Object:hasOwnProperty), which will tell you if a property has been set directly on your object (i.e. *without* trudging through the object's prototype chain):

   ```
   for(var k in myVar) {
     if (myVar.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
       /* ... */
     }
   }
   ```

   And of course be judicious in the use of `hasOwnProperty` in all future `for..in` code that enters the codebase.

You can do both to clean up your codebase *and* be future-proof against other libraries that enter the code that alter `Object.prototype` themselves.

Comment: It is not a library fault, there is a js file that adds the inherit function to the Object prototype like this:

Object.prototype.inherit = function(superClass, superClassName)
{
...
};

You know how to fix this without removing the above? because it is needed in other parts of the page

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some script you are including are modifying the Object.prototype to add its own custom functions.